# Printing a String without any 0's in it

Tags: java, error-handling

So, I have this project where they tell me I have to receive a positive int and change it to a String band I have to work with it digit by didgit.

```
private static String intToString(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("o nº recebido tem de ser 
positivo: " + n);

    // else if((x != (int)x)){
    // throw new IllegalArgumentException("")
    // }

    else {
        String text = "";
        int array[] = new int[(int) (Math.log10(n) + 1)];
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            array[x] = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        for (int x = array.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            text = text + String.valueOf(array[x]);

        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
    return null;
}
```

After I've done that, the next part is removing all the 0's on that String, and I did this:

```
private static int removeZeros(int n) {
    String text = intToString(n);
    for (int l = 0; l < text.length(); l++) {
        if (text[l] != "0") {
            System.out.println("Sick");;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me this error: 
       The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String.

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: `return String.valueOf(n).replace("0", "");`

Comment: your first method doesn't return anything! it always returns null

Answer (score 1):

A String is not an array, although of course it is implemented with an array under the hood.

For a String you can do

```
text.charAt(l)
```

instead of

```
text[l]
```

then compare to '0' (the character) instead of "0" (which is a string).

Answer (score 0):

String can't be indexing by [] it is not an array, Instead you should convert it to char array

Your removeZeros should be:

```
private static int removeZeros(int n) {
    String text = intToString(n);
    char[] ch=text .toCharArray();  
    for (int l = 0; l < ch.length; l++) {
        if (ch[l] != '0') {
            System.out.println("Sick");;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is all wrong. text is still a string, you can't do text[l], moreover ch[l] will give you a char not a String so after fixing the text with ch you should also compare to '0' instead. lastly you should do ch.lenght, not ch.length().

Comment: Updated sorry for mistakes.

Comment: it is '0' not "0". and you have a space after `text` when trying to call ? `toCharArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your **intToString** function is correct , do this

```
private static int removeZeros(int n) {
char[] text = intToString(n).toCharArray();
for (int l = 0; l < text.length(); l++) {
    if (text[l] != "0") {
        System.out.println("Sick");;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

You need Character Array (char[]) data type to iterate through String.Only then you can do text[i] inside the loop.